# Fetching table using mysqli, closing statement before displaying results

Tags: php, mysqli

I am confused if I can do like this:

```
$param = "%{$id}%";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, comp, date FROM stats WHERE date = ? AND name LIKE ? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $param, $_POST['date']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$count_rows = $result->num_rows;
$stmt->close(); // CAN I CLOSE IT HERE

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$row['name'].'
        <td>'.$row['comp'].'
        <td>'.$row['date'].'
    </tr>';
}
```

Question is can i close `$stmt->close();` where i do it now or should i close it after while loop?

I tested and it does work but is it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you are finished using your `$stmt` object, it is practical to close it.

However, I find that I am never calling `$stmt->close();` in any of my projects because php is going to trash them as soon as my script is done anyhow.

Technically, you could have called it one line earlier.

Some leisure reading:

- [$stmt->close() vs $stmt->free_result()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19531195/2943403)
- [When to close Prepared Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6631364/2943403)
- [PHP - close prepared stmt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35169146/2943403)
- [When is the right time to close a prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49224638/2943403)

Comment: So you say that i can use it before while loop?

Comment: Also i did read that if you do not use `$stmt->close();` you could have memory leak?

Comment: Before `$count_rows = $result->num_rows;`

Comment: @Ingus Did you read that online? In that case it is useful to add the link to your comment, otherwise we cannot verify your source. I cannot find any up-to-date source for it. Also, if memory leaks are what you fear, why then do you not use [$result->free()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i did read that in one comment in one page that i cant find anymore. .. Maybe was misread info. I m new to prepared statements so i did not know `free()`

Comment: @Ingus Yeah, see that's exactly my point: "I read somewhere", probably means you're not sure about it. Programming relies on knowing the exact facts, not on rumor. I did find the term 'memory leak' at the bottom of [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php), but that's from 10 years ago.